# Why am I getting this No Route Matches Error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error:

```
Started POST "/admin/reports/2/backfill" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 29 16:09:00 -0500 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/admin/reports/2/backfill"):
```

when I post this form:

```
<%=form_for @report, {:url => report_backfill_path(@report.id), :method => :post} do |f| %>
    <%=label_tag(:days, "number of days to backfill")%>
    <%=select_tag(:days, options_for_select((1..100).to_a.map{|i| [i,i]}))%>
    <%=f.submit "backfill!" %>
<% end %>
```

but the route is defined, check out the output from my rake routes command:

```
report_backfill POST   /admin/reports/:report_id/backfill(.:format)    {:controller=>"reports", :action=>"backfill"}
```

The page containing this form renders fine, it's just when I post it that I get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it post or put?  That's my most common error...

Comment: it is a post, I double checked that a couple of times.

Comment: looks like I have to use form_tag instead of form_for because I'm not posting to one of the standard routes (nor including the standard object fields). Doesn't make any sense, the form renders pretty much the same.

Comment: Could you add in the relevant lines from routes.rb ...

Comment: Does the generated HTML include the hidden input tag that rails uses to support methods such as `PUT` ?

Comment: Please post output of `bundle exec rake routes | grep backfill` (yes everything also the GET,... stuff pls)

Comment: @FrederickCheung you have it correct, it does. I couldn't find a way to get rid of it. using form_tag instead of form_for seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `form_for @report` and `@report` is an existing model, it generates the PUT helpers in the hidden fields, which makes the route engine think it is a PUT request.

Actually, to follow the rails conventions, since you are calling an extra method on the existing report (even though the side effect may be to create things), I would change the routing to use `:put` instead of `:post`, and leave the form alone.